# RabbitMQ + Spring RabbitTemplate: timeout for "convertAndSend"

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq

I've got a fairly simple code that uses Spring's `RabbitTemplate` to send messages to RabbitMQ. The code is **not interested in receiving messages**, it is a simple *fire and forget* scenario.

`rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(exchange, routingKey, payload);`

The template is created like this (please note that I'm using a transacted channel):

```
@Bean
public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
    val rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());
    rabbitTemplate.setChannelTransacted(true);
    rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(jsonConverter());
    return rabbitTemplate;
}
```

I've faced an issue when the RabbitMQ server was overloaded and this call hanged for a long time and never timed out. The connection itself *did not die*, but RabbitMQ server had nearly full RAM and 100% CPU usage, so it wasn't responsive.

Is there a way to configure either Spring's `RabbitTemplate` or the underlying `AmqpTemplate` to time out on a simple send if it blocks for too long?

Comment: if you found any solution please share